# PayPal integration in Xamarin Forms

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tried the sample of AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms but not installed 2.15.5 & 2.15.4 versions in xamarin forms. I followed this below link

https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms

So could you please suggest which package exactly installed in Xamarin forms. I am searching xamarin forums also nobody cannot give exactly solution.

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you're asking - does "Xamarin Forms" include "PayPal.Forms" and you want to know which version of "Paypal.Forms" is included?

Comment: @halfer i am unable to install the "PayPal.Forms" versions from nuget package in visualstudio 2015. and one more question. i am not getting any return value(Success Message) from "PayPal" in xamarin forms.please help me to resolve this issues eating time from past 10 days

Comment: One question at a time please. Why are you not able to install the "PayPal.Forms" versions from nuget package in visualstudio 2015? What **specific problem** are you experiencing?

Comment: @sureshbabulucky Did u get the solution for this? I have integrated Paypal in my project created using VS 2015. Bit late as I recently became active in this

Answer (score 1):

PayPal.Forms is not available form PCL.  What you can do is reference the dll from your iOS/Android project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go to .NET standard and use Stripe, which is the best for in app payment (regarding store policies on which item can be sell using this API)